# Django 1.9 django.db.utils.OperationalError when running initial makemigrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to migrate for the first time on a newly created Django 1.9 project, after I have run "makemigrations new_project". The migrations are created but when I run the "migrate command, I get a django.db.utils.OperationalError for importing a model I created in my forms.py file.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Dealership(models.Model):
country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
postal_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
gps_x = models.FloatField()
gps_y = models.FloatField()
slug = SlugField(max_length=255, original_field='name')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

My forms.py file:

```
import re
from datetime import date, datetime

from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.forms import extras
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from new_project.models import Dealership

form ContactForm(forms.Form):

    DEALERSHIPS = []
    DEALERSHIPS.append(("", ("Select a dealer")))

    for dealer in Dealership.objects.all():
        DEALERSHIPS.append((dealer.name, _(dealer.name)))

    dealer = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=DEALERSHIPS,
        label="Service Center",
        required=True)

....
```

The error is throwing by: "ContactForm(forms.Form):"
This is the error log:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0xb65e9064>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/src/new_project/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from new_project import views
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/src/new_project/views.py", line 19, in <module>
    from new_project.forms import ContactForm, RequestTestDriveForm, \
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/src/new_project/forms.py", line 72, in <module>
    class RequestTestDriveForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/src/new_project/forms.py", line 78, in RequestTestDriveForm
    for dealer in Dealership.objects.all():
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 852, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jcraine/Desktop/projects/new-project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: new_project_dealership
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is my settings.py file:

```
import os

from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 'xy89(rhki@zxc7#)hsfauh!v1^9#^dxs8u@xt8_jo#wt)iqrn)'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'new_project',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'new_project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'new_project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'data', 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-ZA'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Johannesburg'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media') + os.sep

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    'django.template.context_processors.media',
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates'),
)

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False
}

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost')

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    message_constants.DEBUG: 'alert',
    message_constants.INFO: 'alert alert-info',
    message_constants.SUCCESS: 'alert alert-success',
    message_constants.WARNING: 'alert alert-warning',
    message_constants.ERROR: 'alert alert-danger'
}

if DEBUG:  # Don't cache anything in debug
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
            'LOCATION': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cache'),
        }
    }
```

Comment: need to see the complete forms.py but it looks like you calling 'for dealer in Dealership.objects.all()' incorrectly which is causing an error in init, can you show the lines around that, or comment that out an re run

Comment: Do you have this error when you run `./manange.py migrate` ?

Comment: please update the question and add your `settings.py`

Comment: @JamesO I have edited the question such that it reflects my query in forms.py.

Comment: @Pcriulan yes I get the error when I run the migrate command.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have added my settings.py file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `new_project/forms.py` on line 78 you are making a database query on import time of the forms module. This is not supported, you should make any database queries only after the application has finished initializing; usually, this means, when handling a request.

You cannot make database queries while your project is being imported, because it needs to be imported first, so that Django can carry out database migrations, and only then it can create the database tables which are needed in order to perform queries.

**Update:** Seeing the code of your form, have you considered using a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of building the list of choices manually?

For example:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    dealer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dealership.objects.all(),
        label="Service Center",
        required=True)
```

In case you want to customize how the instances of `Dealership` are displayed, you'll find instructions in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question, but how do I go about making the database queries only after the application has finished initializing?

Comment: See update – I think `ModelChoiceField` will be a better fit here than a generic ChoiceField.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in your ContactForm is executed when the python module is loaded, so, it's executed before Django has initialized. Instead, you can provide these choices at initialization time :

```
form ContactForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         dealerships = []
         dealerships.append(("",("Select a dealer")))
         all_dealerships = Dealership.objects.all()
         for dealer in all_dealerships:
             dealerships.append((dealer.name, _(dealer.name)))

         self.fields['dealer'].choices = dealerships

    dealer = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        label="Service Center",
        required=True)
```

But, as said in documentation :

> Note that choices can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. **But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn’t change much, if ever**.

source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#field-choices